# Retrieve page data via flash

Tags: flash, actionscript, flash-builder

So I need to call http://website.com/pagestuff?var1=123&var2=abc and I need to capture the json data returned. I can't for the life of me figure out how to capture a random url's http response data.

```
var apiRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://lb.website.com/public_api/get_data?t_uuid=6e55c370-9a76-4e7e-b5d9-f6fee4034662");
apiRequest.data.toString();
```

Just won't execute. How do I programmatically make a http request with get params and capture the responding data. I know I'm just not looking in the right place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Requests in Actionscript are always asynchronous, therefore you must listen for the `Event.COMPLETE` before data becomes available. The `URLRequest` also does not communicate with external resources by itself, you need to pass it to the `URLLoader` object. Here's an example:

```
private function loadData():void
{
  var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://yourdomain/api/params");
  var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
  loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onDataLoaded);
  loader.load(request);
}

private function onDataLoaded(e:Event):void
{
  e.target.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onDataLoaded);
  var data:String = e.target.data.toString();
  trace(data);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Attempting this methodology now.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you again, I really don't know elbows from ASSociates in flash and thanks to facebook only allowing flash to play media I HAVE to use it.